# Is it possible to link LAPACK, LAPACKE, and BLAS libraries with GCC instead of GFORTRAN?

Tags: gcc, linker, gfortran, lapack, lapacke

I have an application that is written in C. I would like to use the LAPACK library to do some linear algebra calculations. I am using LAPACKE, which is the C interface to LAPACK. The C code compiled fine with GCC, but I am having trouble linking the libraries with GCC. It only works with GFORTRAN. I downloaded the `lapack-3.11.0.tar.gz` file from the [LAPACK website](https://netlib.org/lapack/#_lapack_version_3_11_0). I unpacked the file then I built it. I did not make any changes to the `make.inc.example` file, which was already configured for a linux machine running GNU compilers. Here is how I built it once in the `~/lapack-3.11.0` directory:

```
cp make.inc.example make.inc
make
```

LAPACK built successfully and all of the tests passed. Then, I built LAPACKE. To do this, I simply ran `make` in the `~/lapack-3.11.0/LAPACKE` directory. Similarly, it built successfully and all of the tests passed. Notice that in my case, LAPACK is installed in my home directory and not in a system directory.

To test that I could actually use LAPACKE, I wrote a sample C program that solves a system of equations using `LAPACKE_dgesv()`.

**lapack_test.c**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <lapacke.h>

int main()
{
        int n = 3;
        int nrhs = 1;
        int lda = n;
        int ipiv[n];
        double a[9] = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 10.0};
        double b[3] = {3.0, 3.0, 4.0};
        int info;

        info = LAPACKE_dgesv(LAPACK_ROW_MAJOR, n, nrhs, a, lda, ipiv, b, nrhs);

        if (info == 0)
        {
                printf("Solution: %f %f %f\n", b[0], b[1], b[2]);
        }
        else
        {
                printf("dgsev failed with error code %d\n", info);
        }

        return 0;
}
```

Assuming that `lapack_test.c` is in my home directory, here is how I compiled it and linked the libraries:

```
gcc -I./lapack-3.11.0/LAPACKE/include -c -o lapack_test.o lapack_test.c 
gfortran -o lapack_test lapack_test.o ./lapack-3.11.0/liblapacke.a ./lapack-3.11.0/liblapack.a ./lapack-3.11.0/librefblas.a
```

This gave my no errors. However, GFORTRAN is very inconvenient for my case. In my application I have many C libraries that probably will not link using GFORTRAN. Or at least, I do not think that that they will.

If I use GCC, I get linkage errors. For example, if I simply replace GFORTRAN with GCC in the last step I get a bunch of errors:

```
/usr/bin/ld: ./lapack-3.11.0/liblapack.a(iparmq.o): in function `iparmq_':
iparmq.f:(.text+0x25e): undefined reference to `logf'
/usr/bin/ld: iparmq.f:(.text+0x26b): undefined reference to `lroundf'
/usr/bin/ld: ./lapack-3.11.0/liblapack.a(xerbla.o): in function `xerbla_':
xerbla.f:(.text+0x55): undefined reference to `_gfortran_st_write'
/usr/bin/ld: xerbla.f:(.text+0x60): undefined reference to `_gfortran_string_len_trim'
/usr/bin/ld: xerbla.f:(.text+0x77): undefined reference to `_gfortran_transfer_character_write'
/usr/bin/ld: xerbla.f:(.text+0x87): undefined reference to `_gfortran_transfer_integer_write'
/usr/bin/ld: xerbla.f:(.text+0x8f): undefined reference to `_gfortran_st_write_done'
/usr/bin/ld: xerbla.f:(.text+0x9a): undefined reference to `_gfortran_stop_string'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Seems to be linking the static library `liblapacke.a` with no errors. `liblapack.a` seems to be where the errors are. It is a FORTRAN library, so it makes sense why it would not link correctly using GCC.

Is there a workaround here? Is it worth using LAPACKE? Or, should I try some other way to interface between FORTRAN and C?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference in linking else than some libraries being added automatically. `gfortran` and `gcc` do the same when linking. Only `gfortran` links some libraries like libgfortran or libm automatically while with `gcc` you have to use `-lgfortran` or `-lm`. Otherwise they do the exact same thing.

You can even use the `gcc` command to compile Fortran code and the `gfortran` command to compile C code. Or C++ code. It really does not matter. Just link all the necessary library when linking, depending whether you link with `gcc`, `gfortran`, `g++` or `ld`.

In the end the linking is always done by `ld`, just with some particular flags added by the compiler command.

Finally, to be precise, distinguish GCC, the GNU compiler collection, and `gcc`, the command that calls the C frontend or the GCC's C  compiler. The `gfortran` command calls the Fortran frontend. They share the same backend and middlend. When you call, e.g. `gcc test.f90`, the command recognizes that it is a Fortran source file and will invoke the Fortran frontend for you.

Comment: Yes, simply linking -lgfortran and -lm when compiling with GCC was the solution. Thanks!

Comment: I mainly tried to clarify the incorrect assumptions like "In my application I have many C libraries that probably will not link using GFORTRAN. Or at least, I do not think that that they will." or "It is a FORTRAN library, so it makes sense why it would not link correctly using GCC.". I actually somehow missed the error messages in your post on my mobile phone. We have some duplicates for just solving this one when linking with gcc.